# Find $F(n,k)$ number of monotonic sequences in length $k$ from $n$ elements $\{1,2,3,..,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

I have the following question :

Find $F(n,k)$  number of monotonic sequences in length $k$ from $n$ elements $\{1,2,3,..,n\}$

for example $n=6,k=5$ the sequence $1,2,2,3,5$ is monotonic and the sequence $1,2,2,3,2$ is not monotonic.

**I did the following :**

I looked at $k$ element in the sequences there are three possiblilies :

- The same element as the $k-1$ element in the sequences hences, $F(n,k-1)$
- Doesn't add the next number after $k-1$ element $F(n-1,k)$
- Add the next number after $k-1$ element $F(n-1,k-1)$

Therefore,

$$F(n,k)=F(n,k-1)+F(n-1,k)+F(n-1,k-1)$$

The answer I seen in the answer is different than mine, I think that my answer is true too,

I'll be glad if someone could tell me.

Thank You.

Comment: Each sequence has $k$ elements, not $n$ elements, right? So when you write about the $n$th element, don't you really mean to write about the $k$th element?

Comment: Each sequence is in length $k$ the elements are taken from the group ${1,2,3,..,n}$ $n \geq1$

Comment: Oh I see what I did there, I meant the $k$th element, Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct recurrence is $F(n, k) = F(n, k-1) + F(n-1, k)$.

$F(n, k-1)$ handles the case where we add $n$ to the solution so far. $F(n-1, k)$ handles the case where we choose to skip $n$.

You also have the $F(n-1, k-1)$ case in your recurrence, but this is incorrect. You are now overcounting, because this is the same as first adding $n$ and then skipping $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't quite get what do you mean by add $n$ to the solution, do you mean the element in index $k−1$?

Comment: @JaVaPG $F$ produces monotonic _decreasing_ sequences, $n$ is the element we're considering to add. E.g. $F(6, 2)$ means that we still have 2 elements left to add and we're considering adding $6$ at the moment.

Comment: Is there a closed formula for this recurrence?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom The other answer contains it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just choose $k$ numbers among the $n$ numbers $\,\{1,\dots,n\}$, and if $k>1$, you  order them in one of the two natural orders, so that
$$ F(n,k) = \begin{cases}
n &\text{if }\,k=1,\\[1ex]
2\dbinom{n}{k} &\text{if }\,k>1.
\end{cases}$$