# Deducing number of non decreasing length $k$ sequences of numbers from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The number of non decreasing length $k$ sequences of numbers from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432496/number-of-non-decreasing-sequences-of-length-m).
The recurrence relation is $s(n,k)=s(n-1,k)+s(n,k-1)$ according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624791/find-fn-k-number-of-monotonic-sequences-in-length-k-from-n-elements-1) with $s(n,1)=n$ and $s(1,k)=1$.

My question is: **can you deduce the closed formula from the recurrence relation?**

Comment: It is easy to prove by induction.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on exactly what you mean by "deduce."  I would say that yes, you can solve the recurrence, by solving for successive values of $k$ and spotting the pattern.  When $k=2$, we have $$s(n,2)-s(n-1,2)=s(n,1)=n,$$ so that 
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^m(s(n,2)-s(n-1,2))&=\sum_{n=2}^m n\\ 
s(m,2)-s(1,2)&=\sum_{n=2}^m n\\
s(m,2)&=1+\sum_{n=2}^m n\\ &= \frac{m(m+1)}{2}\\&=\binom{m+1}{2}
\end{align}
$$
Now you can make a similar calculation when $k=3$, and so on, until you guess the answer.

There may be an algorithm that will just spit out the answer, but if so, I don't know it.